# How can I compile a static library into gcc so that the Visual Studio compiler can work with it?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, gcc

My Windows project is an x64 dynamic link library.
Now I'm going to attach the lua interpreter.
I downloaded the lua-5.4.2_Win64_vc14_lib.zip archive (I'm assuming the vc14 in the name means the language standard version), I extracted the .lib file and the include files from that archive, and added it all to my project.

It all works great.

The problem is this:
I know for sure that I need lua version 5.1.4 and it must be a static library

but in the download list of version 5.1.4 the maximum compiled version of the language standard to download is vc11

I do the same and when compiling the dll I get errors:
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol sprintf
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __iob_func
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol fscanf

I read that such errors can occur due to different versions of the language standard (i.e. the static library was built with version vc11, but the dll version is vc14). This assumption is confirmed by my attempts to compile the same version of lua with different versions of the standard. In visual studio settings, I can specify the minimum version of the ISO C++14 standard.

I have no experience with the gcc compiler at all and can't find answers to questions like "what does PLAT=mingw mean?"

I tried 2 solutions to the problem:

1. try to make it so that in the visual studio settings it is possible to specify a version of the language standard lower than 14, but I do not know how to do this. I tried to find information about this and I did not succeed. it is said that standard 14 fully incorporates standard 11 and supports it.
2. try to compile the static lua library from the source files, specifying the required version of the language standard. I tried compiling lua source files step by step using gcc compiler and mingw32-make std=c14 PLAT=mingw command http://lua-users.org/wiki/BuildingLuaInWindowsForNewbies . instead of a lib file, I get a ".a" file. I'm trying to do this #pragma comment(lib, "lua51/bin/liblua.a") in my project and still see a lot of the compilation errors shown above.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a language standard issue. You have made a false assumption regarding the vc11, vc14 suffix that has led you to an inappropriate solution.

Once compiled to machine code, the *source code* language is irrelevant.  The vc11, vc14  refer to the version of MSVC compiler used to build the library, and likely necessary to link to it.

MSVC 14 is the compiler version since Visual Studio 2015 (with numerous subversions).  V11 was introduced with Visual Studio 2012.

I suspect that understanding that, may lead to a different solution than the one you are proposing and asking about.  It is an X-Y problem.

However you may struggle to obtain a VS2012 edition, the earliest available for [download from Microsoft](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/) is 2013. You can obtain 2012 Express (which is a more permissive licence than the current Community edition) from elsewhere, but at your own risk I suggest.

Rather begs the question of why you need this antique Lua version in the first place? Lua 5.1.4 was released in 2008.